# Which Javascript framework/library is best suited for creating a pattern library to support all future framework/library?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, ember.js, web-component

Which Javascript framework/library is best suited for creating a pattern library to support all future framework/library?

In a situation where we need to support all the new upcoming framework for the development for an app, which framework/library is best suited for creating reusable components/patterns for pattern library which can be used across different application as a single source.

Angular/Ember/React/Vanila javascript/Web components?

Comment: This question will lead into an opinion based discussion. Can you ask for specific features? Every framework describes itself as good for reusability; it would be a very bad framework if it does not.

Comment: for specific features, I want to build atomic design(atom, molecule, organism, etc.. ) on one framework which can be used in any framework like plug and play. for e.g. creating a button, date-picker in one framework/library should allow me to import seamlessly to any framework/library and can use that frameworks feature on top of that component/pattern.

Comment: I would say there is no framework that can export anything to other frameworks. For instance, React is based on virtual DOM, altering the JavaScript syntax. AngularJS wouldn't be able to compile things written in ReactJS JSX.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Javascript is *not* "framework/library".

Therefore it's best suited to integrate with any existant or future framework.

Same thing with Web Components... from the moment thy are implemented in the browser they become "Vanilla" Javascript.